# undefined local variable or method `number_to_delimited'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4.2.5.

And in rails API (for v4.2.5.2) I see this helper:

`number_to_delimited(number, options = {})`

> Formats a number with grouped thousands using delimiter (e.g., 12,324). You can customize the format in the options hash.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_delimited

But when I using this help in my views, it throws an error:

`undefined method`number_to_delimited' for #<#:0x0000000b091b30>`

Other helpers, such like `number_to_currency`， all works well. What's wrong with me?

Comment: How are you using it in the view?

Comment: @Pavan I'm using haml and the codes looks like `= number_to_delimited(number)`

Comment: @Hegwin, I answered below, using haml code and rails console. Hope that it help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to call `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper` instead.

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(12345678)
 => "12,345,678"
```

Or you could do also with this:

```
include ActiveSupport::NumberHelper
number_to_delimited(12345678)
 => "12,345,678"
```

UPDATE:

I see you said in comment above that you're using haml code and you can do it like:

```
= ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(12345678)
```

Or

```
- include ActiveSupport::NumberHelper
= number_to_delimited(12345678)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still confused that why I can't use it like other number helpers.

Answer (score 2):

Just include the ActiveSupport::NumberHelper in the ApplicationHelper.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include ActiveSupport::NumberHelper
end
```

Then you can directly use all the number helpers in your views.

```
<%= number_to_delimited(12345678) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`number_to_delimited` is a method in `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper` which cannot be used in the view directly.

Rails provides a couple of number helpers in `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` which are delegated the methods in `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper`.

- number_to_currency
- number_to_human
- number_to_human_size
- number_to_percentage
- number_to_phone
- number_with_delimiter
- number_with_precision

For example, if you want to delimit the number, you should call `number_with_delimiter` instead, which will call `number_to_delimited` in the `ActiveSupport::NumberHelper`.

```
# File actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb, line 244
def number_with_delimiter(number, options = {})
  delegate_number_helper_method(:number_to_delimited, number, options)
end
```

Hope that make sense. Cheers.